# JQuery :first does not select first, but second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, selector

I have a JQuery script which sends a request using **AJAX** to the following url  `https://djjohal.video/video/671/index.html#gsc.tab=0` which contains information of a video song.

I actually want to parse and fetch all the details from the html content I received in the **AJAX** call.

The HTML page contains a total of 3 **div's** each having a class "**.head**", and among them the content of the first **div** is the title of the song that I want to fetch. So for that I tried using the **:first** selector of JQuery like this: `$(PAGE).find("div.class:first").text();` where **PAGE** is the parsed HTML object.

What it does is that instead of selecting the actual first div, it selects the second div with the **head** class which contains useless information.

Here is my JavaScript Code

```
function action(){
    let url = `https://djjohal.video/video/671/index.html#gsc.tab=0`;

    LOG_INFO( "REQUEST SENT..." );

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        success : function(res){
            LOG_INFO( "DATA RECEIVED..." );
            let PAGE = $(res);
            LOG_INFO( $(PAGE).find("div.head:first").text() );
        }
    });
}

function LOG_INFO( MSG ){
    $("body").text( MSG );
    console.log( MSG );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    action();
});
```

Here is the **HTMLcontent** that is received during the **AJAX call**

```
Cannot Paste the whole content in here
```

You can view the content via this link if supported.

[view-source:https://djjohal.video/video/671/index.html#gsc.tab=0](http://view-source:https://djjohal.video/video/671/index.html#gsc.tab=0)

here is the output of the code when executed.

```
REQUEST SENT...
DATA RECEIVED...
Select Format :
```

Where the text "*Select Format :*" is the content of the second div with the **head** class.

You can clearly see that the first div tag with the class "**head**" is the one containing the Title of the Song.

But why can't JQuery see this??

Why does the :first selector selects the second **div**.

What should I do ?? Please help!!

Comment: Can you try `$(PAGE).find('div.head').first()`? As far as I know `:first` doesn't work.

Comment: The `HTML` of the source is very well malformed. With `divs` in the `HEAD` section and so on.

Comment: Go for the `<title>` tag. Same thing. But have to edit the `text`.

Comment: Better yet. Go for `<div class="albumCover">
        <img src="http://djjohalhd.video/data/thumbs/671.jpg" alt="Heathens - Twenty One Pilots ,…`. The `alt` `attribute` of the `image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to clean up your HTML

Why do you have a HEAD tag outside the HTML tags?

Also you shouldn't be putting body content inside the head section.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    success : function(data){
        var responseHtml = $.parseHTML(data);
        songTitle = $.trim(
                $(responseHtml).filter('div.head:first').text());
        alert(songTitle);
    }
});
```

Comment: Woah!! Worked!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `first()`

```
 $(PAGE).find("div.head").first().text();
```

for more information:https://api.jquery.com/first/